# Railsのhelperメソッドの書き方をより良いものにしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, slim

- CMSのコンテンツが全て記載されている場合は、View側でコンテンツを表示する
  という仕様を作るためにhelperメソッドとして下記のようなものを作りました。

※ cms_fragment_content(:text_1)はcomfortable-mexican-sofaというgemを使ってCMSを構築しており、そこから登録しているテキストを取得してくる際に使うhelperメソッドです。

下記のコードで問題なく all_contents? というメソッドは動いているのですが、似たようなコードの繰り返しになってしまっており、もう少しスマートにかけないものかな。。と思い、質問を投稿しました。

色々検索してみたのですが、Rubyは初心者ということもあり、うまく動作するスマートな書き方なものを書くことができませんでした。

別の書き方で、もっとシンプルな書き方あるよ！という場合はアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

```rb
def all_contents?
  cms_fragment_content(:text_1).present?\
  && cms_fragment_content(:text_2).present?\
  && cms_fragment_content(:text_3).present?\
  && cms_fragment_content(:text_4).present?\
  && cms_fragment_content(:text_5).present?
end
```

view側

```
- if all_contents?
  .contents-class
  （以下略）
```

Comment: ここでいう「スマート」とはどういう意味になりますか？一行もしくは短いテキスト量で記述できることを目指していますか？それともコメントがなくてもコードを読めば理解できる理解度の高い記述をしたいということですか？

Comment: @keitaro_so コメントありがとうございます！コードの意味が理解しやすいというのが第一で、同じ処理の記述を繰り返さない（DRY）、であればなお良いと思った次第です。

Answer (score 1):

単純に繰り返しを少し減らすだけなら

```
%i(text_1 text_2 text_3 text_4 text_5).all? { |text_n| cms_fragment_content(text_n).present? }
```

みたいな感じでは書けそうです（試していません）

`(1..5).all? { |n| ~ }` でもいいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

下記のような感じはいかがでしょうか

```
def all_contents?
  (1..5).all? { |i| cms_fragment_content(:"text_#{i}").present? }
end
```